# How get a keyword on the website when user come from ad?

Tags: google-ads-api

how can we get google adword keyword on the website when user come from ads by specific keyword.
I mean how to get this info using javascript or php.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found the solution. We can use AdWords dynamic parameters in links.
Great explanation is here http://certifiedknowledge.org/blog/using-adwords-dynamic-parameters-in-links/